# Change Play Dist snapshot number

Tags: playframework

Using Play 2.0 framework, when I run

```
play dist
```

I always get:

```
xyz-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

How can I increase that number, or specify it manually with each build? End result would be:

```
xyz-1.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `appVersion` and/or `appName` in `project/Build.scala` file.

It will create dist package with new values next time.

Comment: Great. That worked. New to Play, guess this is common knowledge. It would be good as part of Play documentation, as an FYI.

Comment: I think, that you'll realize it easily just next time :) It's quite simple structure initially

Comment: I am facing the same issue in the latest version of play (2.6.10). Could you post a snippet of the fix?